# SQL Updating with random subselect everytime, giving me same value for all rows

Tags: sql, postgresql, random, sql-update, subquery

I have a column with 90% null values, I am trying to use the remaining 10% to pick a value randomly everytime and use it to fill the missing vlues in the exact same table.

this is my table

[image: initial table]

I am using this query to do it on PostgreSQL :

```
UPDATE public."Assure"
SET   "codePostal" = ( 
    SELECT "codePostal" 
      FROM public."Assure"
      WHERE "codePostal" is not NULL
      ORDER BY random() * public."Assure"."CodeAssure_id"
      LIMIT 1 )
WHERE "codePostal" is NULL
```

result :

[image: this is what i get]

Comment: Hmmm. Is that not doing what you want? Also, this is a very strange requirement.

Comment: They way it is set up now you are returning one value from the sub query and using that to `UPDATE` all the rows that have `codePostal IS NULL` to that value.

Comment: @Error_2646 I am trying to update the null values with a diffrent value everytime

Comment: @AdrianKlaver how to set it to get diffrent value for every row ?

Comment: Okay, I see what you are saying.

Answer (score 1):

You can use window functions:

```
update assure a
    set codePostal = a2.codePostal
    from (select a2.*,
                 row_number() over (order by random()) as seqnum,
                 count(*) over () as cnt
          from assure a2
          where codePostal is not null
         ) a2 join
         (select a3.*,
                 row_number() over (order by random()) as seqnum
          from assure a3
          where codePostal is null
         ) a3
         on (a3.seqnum % a2.cnt) = a2.seqnum - 1
    where a3.codeassure_id = a.codeassure_id;
```

In addition to doing what you really want, another advantage is that this does not require sorting all the non-`NULL` values for every row that gets assigned a value.

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=7c07d8602b62f618b597271ff833b98f) is a db<>fiddle illustrating working code.

Comment: for some reason I am getting : 
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "from"
LINE 2:     from (select a2.*,
            ^

how can i fix that ?

Comment: @4212 . . . An `update` is not very useful without a `set`.  I added the missing clause.

Comment: I edit my post to put an image showing an error that i couldn't fix, I hope you can help me with it and I remove it

Comment: @4212 . . . I fixed a typo and added a db<>fiddle.

Comment: Thank you! Thank you so much, Sir

Answer (score 1):

Your code will be fine if you just set aliases for the table that is updated and the table in the subquery:

```
UPDATE Assure a1
SET codePostal = ( 
      SELECT a2.codePostal 
      FROM Assure a2
      WHERE a2.codePostal IS NOT NULL
      ORDER BY RANDOM() * a1.CodeAssure_id
      LIMIT 1)
WHERE a1.codePostal IS NULL
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=97db217c2fff498dadf403717b99ee62).

Comment: Thank you for your answer, your solution makes a lot of sense, I tried it and it just keep executing for ever with 0 changes in the table (same as the other answer).. honestly I think am giving up and I look for an other way to do it, looks like the issue in PostgreSQL itself or idk ..

Comment: @4212 how large is your table?

Comment: 1M rows with like 25K rows with non-NULL "codePostal" values. when I remove that  " * a1.CodeAssure_id " and leave it just "ORDER BY RANDOM() " it executes in seconds, (ofc with same value for all rows which I am trying to avoid)

Comment: @4212 Try with a cte: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=bd65595ee5b3b16d3c14f31a3da72092

Comment: same, executing query for ever without output